# How to check for Object key in javascript for object not inheriting from Object.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node 6.x the `querystring` module parses values into an object that does not extend from `Object.prototype` (Although I have no idea why this change was made).

Given that, what is the expected way to check for query parameters that do not contain a value, i.e. someone called express or koa with `localhost:8080/some/path?keyonly` and I want to check for the presence of `this.query.keyonly`? I expected that I could do `this.query.hasOwnProperty('keyonly')` which obviously doesn't work. What's the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the background behind the change, see the original PR [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/6055).

In general, you should not rely on `foo.hasOwnProperty()` since `hasOwnProperty` could be easily reassigned to something else (hence the reason for the `querystring` change -- imagine someone calling your web service with something like http://example.org/foo?hasOwnProperty=hahacrashed).

As far alternatives, you could just check if the property is defined, for example:

```
var qs = querystring.parse('foo=bar');
if (qs.foo !== undefined) {
  // ...
}
```

You could also do something like:

```
var qs = querystring.parse('foo=bar');
if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(qs, 'foo')) {
  // ...
}
```

but that isn't as efficient because `hasOwnProperty()` performs additional (and unnecesary in the case of `querystring` now) checks and uses `.call()` which is less efficient

Comment: incidentally I could also do `Object.keys(this.query).includes('somekey')`, which is readable but probably least efficient.

Comment: Yes, I would bet using `Object.keys()` would be even less efficient (if for no other reason than it makes the GC work harder than necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use `Object.hasOwnProperty.call( this.query, "keyonly" )`. I set up a bit of a contrived test case and it appears to work:

```
const querystring = require("querystring");

const qs = "keyonly&keyvalue=valuekey";
const result = querystring.decode(url);

console.log(Object.hasOwnProperty.call( result, "keyonly" )); // true
```

The `&keyvalue=valuekey` part isn't necessary for it to work, I just wanted to verify that it wouldn't interfere somehow.